# Embedding a Custom HTML5 Player on Facebook

Tags: facebook, html5-video

Does Facebook provide a way to embed a custom HTML5 video player while sharing using Open Graph Tags? I know a flash player can be shared and have done so. I am building a custom HTML5 Video Player with a few overlays on top of the actual video. Is there a way to share the player and the video as is on Facebook?

Comment: You can only embed SWF players

Comment: is this still the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to embed HTML

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because as of today, there is no way which facebook provides to embed a custom HTML5 video player while sharing.

Comment: @ Colenso Castellino 
Seems there are some players already.
https://www.facebook.com/soundcloud

Comment: @LalithJayasinghe Yes some like soundcloud is testing that feature. When it will be available for everyone it will be on developers.facebook.com/docs