# How to embed my custom htlm5 audio player into facebook post

Tags: html, facebook, audio

I have custom html5 audio player in my website.
I also have facebook sharing button in my website. Now when users click share button only url of my site gets shared.
What I want is to be able to share and embed audio player as well in sharing.
Any help would be more than appreciation

Comment: Not possible. You can only embed a flash player or an mp4 video directly.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't allow sharing of HTML, so you can't share your custom HTML player. You can only share link to it:

> www.yourwebsite.com/player

Comment: I want to embed html5 audio player not video...

Comment: what about mp3 file?

Comment: any file can be shared!

Comment: Here is a solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647044/embedding-a-custom-html5-player-on-facebook