# My own html5 player does not play on facebook; why?

Tags: html, facebook, video

Since almost five years, we are developping a video player and its related embed page for sharing video content.

Today, the only way to embed on facebook our player is to use flash tecnology. 
Many of our customers want to use our html5 player, But today we could not find a way to embed it.

I have seen that vimeo player and youtube player are embeddable into facebook; for us and for our future, is very important to make our player HTML5 embeddable into facebook.

One years ago, a stackoverflow user answered: "No, it is not possible to embed HTML" ([Embedding a Custom HTML5 Player on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647044/embedding-a-custom-html5-player-on-facebook))

Is still impossible? 
Or rather, there is a way to embed my html5 player on facebook?
In 2016, it is a big problem for me to don't use my html5 player into facebook.

Obviously to solve this problem, I am available to a confrontation with a facebook developer...

Comment: This is still not possible, you should keep an eye on the developer blog here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/ as all new features will be announced there.