# html flash player on facebook with BiliBili

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, flash

Just like in this question [Embedding a Custom HTML5 Player on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647044/embedding-a-custom-html5-player-on-facebook) I have built a custom videojs player that I want to embed on facebook, which only accepts flash - .swf to be specific.

Now I am completely oblivious on how flash works, but I just found this repository https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js, which seems to create a flash player in HTML. Does anybody know, if I can use this to embed my html player on Facebook?

Sorry if that question is a naive question.

Comment: Did you read this from FB? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @mlegg Yes, but that one is the other way around: Embedding facebook videos on your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)**
It's not possible to embed a custom HTML5 player. You can embed an custom Flash player only. See my other [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367646/how-to-embed-my-own-flash-video-player-in-facebook/26399297#26399297) about embedding Flash-based custom players.

You need a `swf` file, that means you need a *Flash application* with code in there to load and play your video files. The swf must be uploaded to your `https` server.

**(2)**
That [**Bilibili link**](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js) is for handling files saved in flv video format (`flv` means `FL`ash `V`ideo fomat).

It just converts (moves) the data to mp4 video format since they both can hold same content & where the mp4 is then decoded by browser (ie: with *HTML5*, not *Flash* plugin). That's their meaning of "*...Playing Flash video with HTML5*"